RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND while using Bootsfaces 1.6.0-SNASPHOT on WIldfly 31
I am currently trying to upgrade a java facelet thats using Bootsface to jakarta and i ran into the problem that in the deployed app.xhtml a script is refered by 
I am using bootsfaces 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT since there is no Jakarta compatible Version and Wildfly 31.0.0.Final. The UI is loaded an looks ok but if i select an row in the datatable i get an "Uncaught ReferenceError: jsf is not defined" in "jakarta.faces.resource/js/bsf.js?ln=bsf:24" and the onselect option is not executed but the console.log execution does work.
app.xhtml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
      xmlns:f="jakarta.faces.core"
      xmlns:h="jakarta.faces.html"
      xmlns:ui="jakarta.faces.facelets">
        ....
    <h:form>
        <b:container span="12" class="content-container">
            <b:row>
                <b:column span="6">
                    <b:panel collapsible="false">
                        <f:facet name="heading" >
                            <h:outputText value="Databases " class="panel-header"/>
                            <b:icon name="refresh" onclick="#{DBManager.initializeDBList()}" update="@form:**:changeStatus @form:**:statusBadge @form:**:DBTable" disabled="false"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <b:row>
                            <b:dataTable value="#{DBList}" var="db" select="true" onselect="console.log(typeOfSelection + ' ' + indexes + ' has been selected');#{DBManager.onSelect()};" selection-mode="single" update="@form:**:selectedDB" page-length='10' info="false" border="false" id="DBTable">
                                <b:dataTableColumn value="#{db.key}" label="dbKeys" order='asc'/>
                                <b:dataTableColumn label="Status" orderable="false">
                                <b:badge value=" " class="#{DBManager.getStatusClass(db)} table-badge"/>
                                </b:dataTableColumn>
                                ...

